# How to extract specific value from each element of an array and turn them into an array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to extract the name and rate from each element of the array below, and turn them into an array of object

```
[
  'BTCUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t0.0100%\t0.01%\t0.3000% / -0.3000%\t0.3000% / -0.3000%',
  'ETHUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t0.0100%\t0.01%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%',
  'BCHUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t-0.0135%\t0.01%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%'
]
```

The following is what i expect to get:

```
[
{"name":BTCUSDT, "rate":0.01%},
{"name":ETHUSDT,"rate":0.01%},
{"name":BCHUSDT,"rate":0.01%},
]
```

Appreciate for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr = [
  'BTCUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t0.0100%\t0.01%\t0.3000% / -0.3000%\t0.3000% / -0.3000%',
  'ETHUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t0.0100%\t0.01%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%',
  'BCHUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t-0.0135%\t0.01%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%'
];
var data = [];
const result = arr.reduce((data, value) => {
  const splitArray = value.split(' ');
  var params = {
    name: splitArray[0],
    rate: splitArray[1].split('\t')[4]
  }
  data.push(params);
  return data;
}, [])

const output = result;
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `arr.reduce()`

```js
const arr = [
  'BTCUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t0.0100%\t0.01%\t0.3000% / -0.3000%\t0.3000% / -0.3000%',
  'ETHUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t0.0100%\t0.01%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%',
  'BCHUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t-0.0135%\t0.01%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%'
];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  debugger;
  const splitArr = item.split(' ');
  acc.push({
    [splitArr[0]]: splitArr[1].split('\t')[4]
  });
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of array mapping and string splitting to achieve this:

```
const arr = [
  'BTCUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t0.0100%\t0.01%\t0.3000% / -0.3000%\t0.3000% / -0.3000%',
  'ETHUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t0.0100%\t0.01%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%',
  'BCHUSDT Perpetual\t8h\t05:14:44\t-0.0135%\t0.01%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%\t0.3750% / -0.3750%'
];

const result = arr.map(item => {
  const elements = item.split('\t');
  const name = elements[0].split(" ")[0];
  return {
    name,
    rate: elements[4]
  };
});

console.log(result);
```